# Codeigniter select_sum generate wrong query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I worked on a [Codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com) 2 project, there I have an [active record](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html) like:

```
$query = $this->db->select_sum('Cardit * GPA', 'sum')
                  ->get('marks_info');
```

It generates query like:

```
SELECT SUM(`Cardit` * `GPA`) AS `sum` FROM `marks_info`
```

Recently I migrated my project to Codeigniter 3, but the same active record generated little different query like:

```
SELECT SUM(`Cardit *` `GPA`) AS `sum` FROM `marks_info`
```

that is wrong, it includes * with *Cardit* (**'Cardit *'**) in SUM section.

Difference:

[image]

Can anybody tell me, how can I solve this issue in CodeIgniter 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will give you your expected output

```
$query = $this->db->select('sum(Cardit * GPA) sum')->get('marks_info');
```

Comment: This way I can do. But my issue is on code generation using the latest CI.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid backticks within the query. You can assign **false** to `protect_identifiers` like :

```
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
```

and run your query accordingly.

Comment: No. This is not working. Also, this would be `protect_identifiers` because the latest CI version removes `_`.